# Path-connected does not imply convex

Tags: convex-analysis, path-connected

I'm trying to prove that A subset of the Complex numbers which is path-connected does not imply that it is convex.

Any help?

Comment: You can do so with a contradiction of a set that is path connected, say an annulus, and the path being a straight line from one side to the other

Answer (score 4):

I interpret "does not imply" as "look for a counterexample".

Convex means that the straight line between any two points in a set in still in that set.

Path connected means that you can find a path in the set between any two points in that set, which does not have to be a straight line.

So you could look at $\mathbb{C}\backslash \{0\}$ for example and try out the definitions on the points $-1$ and $1$.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Let $A,B$ and $C$ be the points inside the region **${A}$**.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  (1) Is the unit circle (not disk) path connected?  (2) Is a deleted neighbourhood of a point convex?

Answer (score 1):

Consider any path that isn't a straight line or line segment. This set is path connected but not convex.