# When does path connectedness implies convexity?

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis, examples-counterexamples, connectedness, path-connected

It is easy to see that every convex set is path connected.
What are some examples so that converse holds (not counting the (trivial) one dimensional case)?
Is there a nice topology so that this holds?

[Related question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2586115/path-connected-does-not-imply-convex/2586289#2586289)

Comment: Since you can glue arbitrary path-connected spaces together in pretty arbitrary ways, I think it rather depends what you mean by "nice".

Comment: Convexity is not a topological property, but rather a geometric one. The disc (convex) is homeomorphic to a fat $U$ (not convex). If you want spaces which are "convex up to homeomorphism", for example, then there are theorems which state that simply connected surfaces with sufficiently regular boundary are homeomorphic to a disk.

Comment: A 'fat U' is the closure of a "U"-shaped open set (in $\mathbb{R}^2$). For example, take the "thin U set" $$A=\left\{(\cos(t),\sin(-t)):0< t<\pi\right\}$$ and the ''fat U set" $${\mathrm{\bf U}}=\left\{x:d(x,A)\leq1/3\right\},$$ where $d(x,A)=\inf\left\{d(x,a):a\in A\right\}$ is the distance from a point $x$ to the set $A$. Mentioning a "fat (whatever)-shaped set" we just mean a set - usually closed - that resembles a (whatever), and has a large interior (e.g. it is regular closed). This is just a colloquial intuitive terminology.

Answer (score 2):

If the space is such that only constant functions are continuous (space with trivial topology), then the only path-connected sets are singletons, which are convex.

Comment: But in this topology not all convex sets are path-connected (unless the space has only one point).